# Consume data from wsdl and expose the data as Rest or soap through Informatica cloud to be consumed by Salesforce application

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I need help on this guys.

I have a scenario where i have to consume data from wsdl object into Informatica cloud and expose the data through REST or SOAP from Informatica cloud to be consumed by Salesforce application. It is a Cloud Application Integration scenario. How do I achieve this? Can anyone explain step by step process provide I am new to this integration. This is the only solution I have to do.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have read the documentation Informatica provides that tells you how to do this? If so, what precisely are you having issues with?

Comment: I went through some of documentations but couldn't exactly find this kind of particular scenario. Can you please kindly guide me to the document you are referring to? That would be really great full.

Comment: Creating a WSDL source: https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/web-services-provider-guide/working-with-web-service-sources-and-targets/importing-a-web-service-source-or-target-definition/importing-a-web-service-source-or-target-definition-from-a-wsdl.html.  Create an API: https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-api-manager/current-version/api-manager-guide/preface.html